# How do i prevent creating the same user with the same info?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

How do I check if the user already created the same LRN ?
   and when I press the save button twice it creates two user with the same info
   how do I prevent it ?

```
jQuery('#save_voter').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var FirstName = jQuery('.FirstName').val();
var LastName = jQuery('.LastName').val();
var Section = jQuery('.Section').val();
var Year = jQuery('.Year').val();
var LRN = jQuery('.LRN').val();
var Password = jQuery('.Password').val();

e.preventDefault();
if (FirstName && LastName && Section && Year && LRN && Password){   
var formData = jQuery(this).serialize();    

jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:  'save_student.php',
    data: formData,
         success: function(msg){
        showNotification({
message: "Student Successfully Added",
type: "success", 
autoClose: true, 
duration: 5 

});
```

Comment: you have to check the existence of user before inserting by doing this we can filter the data..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By creating a unique constraint on the username field. It seems that in your case the LRN field is the username field. Make it unique by

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD UNIQUE INDEX uname on users (LRN);
```

Then you can try something like this to tell the end user that the username is duplicated.

```
try{
   $res =$connection->query(your user insert);
}catch(Exception $e){
   echo 'Sorry already exists';
}
```

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem :D but how can i make an error ? where it says that "LRN already exist" ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do 3 steps :

- Check manually First Name and Last Name already exists or not in PHP file
- In resultset contains more than 0 records, then return false which means record already exists.
- In JQuery, if its getting false, then show an error message that `record already exists`.

Further, as @kongkang said in comments that the field LRN is as username.

then still you need to do 3 steps :

- Make that field as `unique` in database table
- Add if condition on insertion query (PHP File) that if return false it means record already exists
- in Jquery, if returning value is false, then show error message.

Comment: I don't think this can assure the atomicity.

Comment: @HaotianLiu : can you explain whats missing ?

Comment: Maybe I did not get it correct. But in this condition: two or more users registering the same username, and in the check process, both returned true, but there will then be duplicate in the database. So there has to be constraint of UNIQUE key in the database, and PHP return should be also based on whether the insertion is success or not.

Comment: Well, in jquery code, there is no username field. It contains first name and last name so we can add conditions based on these two fields.

Comment: the username field on my jquery was LRN .

Comment: @kangkong ah ok, let me update answer. then you can mark as correct and vote up.

Comment: @NaveedRamzan sure .

Answer (score 0):

Add a unique index to your database for a unique field.I hope LRN is there for you. Then

```
MYSQL:
ALTER TABLE users ADD UNIQUE (LRN)
SQL SERVER: 
ALTER TABLE [users] ADD CONSTRAINT UC_LRN UNIQUE ([LRN]);
```

When you try to insert duplicate LRN database error will come automatically for Codeigniter. Without it you have to check manually.